# Pivoting the table with Time intervals

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, time-series, pivot, pivot-table

So I have a such pySpark DataFrame:

```py
+------+--------------+---------------+----------+----------+
|A_ID  |B_ID          |C_ID           | BEGIN    |   END    |
+------+--------------+---------------+----------+----------+
| 55264|     12       |         4     |2001-01-01|2012-08-05|
| 54897|     12       |         4     |2001-11-01|2012-11-30|
|  8222|     12       |         5     |2001-08-01|2012-12-31|
| 25001|     12       |         4     |2001-10-01|2015-08-30|
| 40001|     12       |         5     |2001-11-01|2012-12-31|
|  8217|     12       |         5     |2001-05-01|2020-12-31|
| 40002|     12       |         5     |2001-05-01|2009-05-01|
| 25002|     12       |         4     |2001-10-01|2020-05-30|
|  8073|     13       |         3     |2002-05-05|2003-05-04|
...
```

I want to pivot the DataFrame with Multiindexing. I'd like to have two vertical IDs - A_ID and B_ID. In the horizontal line should be weeks, starting from the oldest begin date. Value would base on C_ID where 0 means that in specific week there arent any C_ID, 1 means C_ID has some value in this week, 2 means more than one unique C_ID in specific week for the A_ID/B_ID row. Would be great to have some info about all passed days for C_ID.

Finally it could looks like this:

```py
+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
|    Weeks  | w1  | w2  | w3  | ....
+-----+-----+
|B_ID | A_ID|
+-----+-----+------------------
| 12  |55264|  0  |  1  |  1  |
|     |82226|  2  |  1  |  0  |
|     |80732|
|     |55264|
|     |40001|
|     |54897|       etc...
| 13  |80732|
|     |32444|
...
```

How can I make it?

Comment: how do you create the weeks - w1, w2, w3, ...? which date column are you using?

Comment: I thought about starting from ```begin```column, ending on ```end```.

Comment: what will be the first record's week then?

Comment: Case of specifc IDs combination, where 1 will be set if in the first possible week there were C_ID. Lets say ```B_ID``` = 1, ```A_ID``` = 1, ```C_ID``` = 4, with dates ```1.1.2011 - 14.1.2011```, then in pivoted table: ```B_ID``` = 1, ```A_ID``` = 1, ```w1``` = 1, ```w2``` = 1, ```w3``` = 0. etc. for other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Replicate the data

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
from pyspark.sql import Window

cols = ["A_ID", "B_ID", "C_ID", "BEGIN", "END"]

data = [(55264, 12, 4, "2001-01-01", "2012-08-05"),
    (54897, 12, 4, "2001-11-01", "2012-11-30"),
    (8222,  12, 5, "2001-08-01", "2012-12-31"),
    (40001, 12, 5, "2001-11-01", "2012-12-31"),
    (8217,  12, 5, "2001-05-01", "2020-12-31"),
    (40002, 12, 5, "2001-05-01", "2009-05-01"),
    (25002, 12, 4, "2001-10-01", "2020-05-30"),
    (8073,  13, 3, "2002-05-05", "2003-05-04")]

df_data = (spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=cols)
            .select("A_ID", "B_ID", "C_ID", 
                     F.col("BEGIN").cast("date"),
                     F.col("END").cast("date")))
```

### Calculate and pivot:

##### 1) If you want all weeks in the columns starting with the first, create df_weeks and later join with the resulting dataframe before pivot. If you want numbered columns, use weeks_no to groupby and pivot in 2) below:

```
w = Window.orderBy("week")
df_weeks = (df_data
             .agg(F.min(F.date_trunc("week", "BEGIN")).cast("date").alias("start"), 
                  F.max(F.date_trunc("week", "END")).cast("date").alias("end"))
        .withColumn("week", F.explode(F.expr('sequence(start, end, interval 1 week)')))
        .withColumn("week_no", F.row_number().over(w))
       ).select("week", "week_no")
```

##### 2) create rows for each date betwen BEGIN and END, truncate with date_trunc to get week start for each date, groupby by week, A_ID, B_ID and do the count of distinct C_ID values, join with df_dates, then pivot and fill null values with 0:

```
df = (df_data
       .withColumn("dates", F.explode(F.expr('sequence(BEGIN, END, interval 1 week)')))
       .withColumn("week", F.date_trunc("week", "dates").cast("date"))
       .join(df_weeks, "week", "right")
        .groupBy("week", "A_ID", "B_ID")
        .agg(F.countDistinct("C_ID").alias("count"))
        .groupBy("A_ID", "B_ID")
        .pivot("week")
        .agg(F.first("count"))
        .fillna(0))
```

Comment: So, as I see there's count that checks overlaped C_ID for specific weeks right?

Comment: coundDistinct should take care of that, to only count unique values